# How to display only the last paragraph of text in a file using cat?

Tags: cat

I have been set a challenge for an assignment at school and can't find the answer anywhere. I have a text file called **tomtextfile** and the question states 'Use the **cat** command, suitably modified, to show only the last paragraph of your text. How is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible using only `cat`. Are you sure you are not allowed to use additional tooling? (such as `sed`, `awk`, or `cut`)

Comment: All it says is that I can modify it, maybe something to do with **tail** ?

Comment: If it helps, the previous question was 'Use the **cat** command, suitably modified, to: show the contents of tomtextfile, with the occurence of  a particular word, chosen by you, highlighted. The answer was: 'cat tomtextfile | grep my'

Comment: So yes, you are allowed to use different commands. I wouldn't say piping to a different command (grep in this instance), is *modifying* a command, but that might be a terminology issue.

Comment: You'll have to explain how the text file is structured. Is a paragraph, for example, a set of lines separated by an empty line or a unbroken line of text terminated by a newline? The treatment of newlines may affect the options used to modify how paragraphs and lines are parsed by the commands in the pipeline.

Comment: I bet you're fun at parties. I just found the answer a week after i posted the question because the answers I received were wrong, I thought I'd notify everyone that I had found it but then people like you come along. Just leave it out man I'm new to this website. @JakeGould

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option by using tac (reverse cat):

```
tac tomtextfile | grep "^$" -B1000000 -m1 | tac | grep -v "^$"
```

Comment: The answer for me was: cat tomtextfile | tail -n 1

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

> cat tomtextfile | awk -v RS="" ' {last=$0} END {print last} '